# How to install previous version of package or how to solve dependiences issue?

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I have this problem:

```
libffi-dev : Depends: libffi6 (= 3.1-2+deb8u1) but 3.2.1-6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

and `apt-get install -f` doesn't help. How I can solve the problem or downgrade libffi6 ?

Answer (score 0):

If the other version of the package is still available via your configured repositories, you can specify the version number when asking for the package to be installed:

```
apt-get install libffi6=3.1-2+deb8u1
```

Since package downgrades aren't supported or well-tested, there's a chance this might break during package installation, but for a library package the chances are quite low.

I'd wonder why you've ended up in this precarious situation, though.  Based on the version numbers you're quoting, it looks like you've got (or had) a mixed system of Debian Jessie and Stretch.  I'd recommend not doing that, if you're not up to the task of managing version inter-relationship problems like this one.  Just set all your package repos to stretch, do a dist-upgrade, and go forth and stress no more.